# ハッシュの値を合計したい

Tags: ruby

初歩的な質問で申し訳ないですがお願いします。

```
{"key1"=>"3.5", "key2"=>"4.1", "key3"=>"2.9", "key4"=>"3.2", "key5"=>"2.6"}
```

というハッシュがあった場合に右辺の数値の合計を計算したいのですが上手くいきません。
どうしたら計算できるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Enumerable#sum` が利用できます。 https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/method/Enumerable/i/sum.html

```
h = {"key1"=>"3.5", "key2"=>"4.1", "key3"=>"2.9", "key4"=>"3.2", "key5"=>"2.6"}
h.values.map(&:to_f).sum
# => 16.3
```

Answer (score 3):

Yuki Inoue さんの回答で既に解決したようで良かったですが、

たぶん、質問者さんがうまくいかなかったのは、値が文字列だからではないでしょうか?

なので、Yuki Inoue さんの回答では、これを数値に変換するために `.map(&:to_f)` が
入っています。

数値になってしまえば、あとは合計するだけなので、問題なくできると思います。

以下のコードと実行結果を見て、どのメソッドを呼んで何が返ってきて、
それにどのメソッドを呼んで何が返ってきているか、
理解を深めると良いでしょう。

コード:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

h = {"key1"=>"3.5", "key2"=>"4.1", "key3"=>"2.9", "key4"=>"3.2", "key5"=>"2.6"}

p h
p h.values
p h.values.map(&:to_f)
p h.values.map(&:to_f).sum
```

実行結果:

```
luna:~ % ruby test.rb
{"key1"=>"3.5", "key2"=>"4.1", "key3"=>"2.9", "key4"=>"3.2", "key5"=>"2.6"}
["3.5", "4.1", "2.9", "3.2", "2.6"]
[3.5, 4.1, 2.9, 3.2, 2.6]
16.3
luna:~ %
```

Answer (score 0):

```
h = {"key1"=>"3.5", "key2"=>"4.1", "key3"=>"2.9", "key4"=>"3.2", "key5"=>"2.6"}
h.values.reduce(0) {|sum, i| sum + i.to_f }
```